# Image not showing up inside parent div

Tags: image, html

[Here](http://jsbin.com/ecuH/1/edit) is the bin. An image on the internet that i have linked to is not showing up on Netbeans IDE v7.2, but for some reason it works just fine in jsBin.

The img:

```
<a href=""><img id='logo' src="http://www.logomaker.com/logo-images/3518dfc2d4b42754.gif" alt="logo maker logo creator"/></a>
```

I can't put the href there because it won't allow a localhost on SO.

The CSS:

```
#banner {
    background: white;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 150px;
}
#logo {
    border: 0px;
}
```

### Edit:

Screenshot:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: You are not going to be able to put a localhost anywhere online.  Could you do a screenshot maybe?

Comment: I will. I know that i'm not going to put localhost online.

Comment: I'm not sure Logomaker.com likes you hotlinking images on their server, not to mention that this is bad for your site itself in terms of speed and therefor SEO. Does the same problem occur if you save the image locally (as you should) and include that instead?

Comment: I don't know. I haven't tried it.

Comment: @JeroenvandenBroek I never learned how to access photos from my own computer.

Comment: Just don't include the hostname. If your HTML file is in C:\Website and your image called "logo.jpg" is in C:\Website\images, then you can use `<img src="images/logo.jpg">`. Alternatively you can use `<img src="file://C:/Website/images/logo.jpg">` but this is obviously a wrong thing to do as your computer is not accessible from the web, so none of your visitors can see the image that way when they can with the first way I mentioned. The same goes for links by the way, don't include localhost and you won't have to replace all the links later on.

Comment: is that in mac or both?

Comment: Macs obviously don't have a C:\. Relative urls (`images/logo.jpg`) work on every OS.

Comment: I tried using the option mentioned and it still is hidden. let me try it in jsBin.

Comment: in jsBin with the option mentioned, it shows as a little box with a document icon in it. It doesn't show the actual image.